# Improper integral of Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

Is it true that $\int_0^\infty \delta(x-\alpha)d\alpha = \int_0^\infty \delta(\alpha - x)d\alpha$? Note that x is **NOT** the variable here.
It's said that the delta function is even so the expression stands.
But isn't those translated versions of the original delta function? Does the even property still hold?

Comment: It seems to disturb you that the integral is with respect to $\alpha$ ... why not exchange the role of $x$ and $\alpha$ then? These are just notations!

Comment: @LL3.14 Sure we can switch $d\alpha$ with $dx$, but the I'm still confused by the question

Comment: Both integral equals to the Heaviside Step Function of variable $x$, so  they are the same.